# How robust is repeating a piece of code to measure it's execution time?

Tags: c#, performance

Let's say I want to measure how long `MyFunction()` executes.

Let's also say that `MyFunction()` executes fast (a few milliseconds) and that Stopwatch cannot measure the function time with a good enough precision.

I then will put `MyFunction()` inside of a loop which executes 1,000,000 times and measure that. I will time the execution of the loop and then divide the result by the number of times the loop executed.

The questions are:

- How accurate is this measurement? I basically want to know how long
  the FIRST execution of `MyFunction()` takes, not how long the average
  takes.
- Does the time executing the same function scale linearly? Does that
  depend on the properties of `MyFunction()` (so some kind of  caching
  is used)? What are those properties?

Comment: The precision of Stopwatch is greater than "a few milliseconds"... Just as a remainder, *before* benchmarking a method, execute it at least once, so that it is Jitted by the CLR

Comment: The first execution of the function *may* involve the code being compiled (which won't happen on subsequent calls). This will likely make the timing for the very first call unrepresentative.

Comment: Note that if we are speaking of things like "2 additions and a multiplication", then we are in a range much smaller than millisecond. At that range, `Stopwatch` doesnt work :-)

Comment: As well as jitting, the first execution a particular method may be slower because of loading of caches, database buffering etc.

Comment: @Polyfun And then in general, a method could be accessing for the first time objects with `static` members/constructors, and loading whole assemblies... So many things happen in the first run of a method...

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a two part [article](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one) about benchmarking which could be of some interest here.

Comment: Note that if your code will actually run only once in your actual solution, or at least very occasionally so caches etc get cleared,  then the first run may actually be the most representative for all the reasons others have given above. You also need to keep an eye to make sure your process if not swapped in and out if you really are using a stopwatch with the longer runs.

Comment: Why do you care about the first execution  at all? It is not representable for the performance of the method in general and a single run can also not be a performance issue.

Comment: @xanatos the precision of Stopwatch on my machine is about 3 MHz making the precision 0.0003ms. Stopwatch is not based on DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you run `MyFunction()` 1,000,000 times in 3 seconds.

You now know:

1. You can at least sometimes run `MyFunction()` in a time less than or equal to 3μs, on similar data and with similar cache and jitter situations.
2. It probably runs faster than an equivalent method that takes 3.5 seconds, as long as the tests are truly equivalent. (But 3.01 is too close to be sure unless this repeats consistently).
3. It probably runs slower than an equivalent method that takes 2.5 seconds, as long as the tests are truly equivalent. (But 2.99 is too close to be sure unless this repeats consistently).

You do not know:

1. How much the time is affected on first call by jitting, static constructors, and memoisation of values that are either static or related to the particular values used.
2. How much the time is affected by the method still being accessible from the instruction cache (or indeed, whether it is).
3. How much the time is affected by the data used still being accessible from the data cache (or indeed, whether it is).
4. How consistent the time is subsequent to first run; is it a steady 3μs per run, or more often 1μs with some occasional large delays?
5. Just what portion of the time was spent on the looping rather than the running.

These five things you don't know (or four if you do a run prior to the loop to at least reduce the impact of the first one) mean you don't know an awful lot in an absolute sense.

But the three things you do know can be very useful relative to other possible approaches, or if you're clearly above or below a certain threshold (if you need to beat 2μs you're screwed, if you need to beat 500ms you're fine, if you need to consistently beat 4μs then you don't know if you have).